# Is it possible for symfony/panther to wait for some elements n times?

Tags: php, web-crawler, symfony-panther

Below is my **`PHP`** code and I am looking for a custom callback function that I need to make sure I can get more than 5 elements with css identifier "`a[data-selenium='neighbor-link']`" and I will fetch the html content.

Is it possible?
Thank you.

```
$client = \Symfony\Component\Panther\Client::createChromeClient(null, $options2);
$client->request('GET', $row['url']);
$client->waitFor("a[data-selenium='neighbor-link']");
```

Comment: There is similar behavior of php-webdriver . You can see the "Custom conditions" on https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver/wiki/HowTo-Wait

Comment: $driver->wait()->until(
    function () use ($driver) {
        $elements = $driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('li.foo'));

        return count($elements) > 5;
    },
    'Error locating more than five elements'
);